# how to convert `2021-3-31 15:51:38` to `2021-3-31 15:51:38` not `2021-3-31 3:51:38` in Postgresql or Javascript

Tags: javascript, postgresql, date

I would like to convert string to date, it can be an empty string or any other string, so I use the below javascript code to convert the string to date, but below code converted `2021-3-31 15:51:38` to `2021-3-31 3:51:38`, it's not correct, how to use SQL(Postgresql) to do it? Such as `SELECT TO_DATE(NULLIF(dt, ''),'yyyymmdd' or ’yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss' or 'yyyy-MM-dd')`?

```
if(somedate==null){

}
else if(somedate.length==10){
    somedate=str2date(somedate,"yyyy-MM-dd")
}else if(somedate.length==8){
    somedate=str2date(somedate,"yyyyMMdd")
}else if (somedate.length==19){
    somedate=str2date(somedate,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
}else{
    somedate=null
}

somedate=date2str(somedate,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')
```

Comment: `2021-3-31 3:51:38` is a string, not a date object. It's probably the string representation of your date object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, that would be:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(
          strcol,
          CASE length(strcol)
             WHEN 10 THEN 'YYYY-MM-DD'
             WHEN  8 THEN 'YYYYMMDD'
             WHEN 19 THEN 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
          END
       )
FROM mytab;
```

The `CASE` expression will result in NULL if none of the `WHEN` conditions match.